# Attaching an image to an Ellipse programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

When I run this code, I get a black screen until i maximise the application? Also, I don't think its picking up the image file neither. Within Visual Studio, I made a new folder and added the image to this folder.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.Width = 300;
    canvas.Height = 300;
    canvas1.Children.Add(canvas);

    Ellipse hand = new Ellipse();
    hand.Height = 30;
    hand.Width = 30;
    /*
    BrushConverter bc = new BrushConverter();
    Brush brush = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("Red");
    hand.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    */
    ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
    myBrush.ImageSource =
        new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/Hand.png", UriKind.Relative));
    hand.Fill = myBrush;

    Canvas.SetLeft(hand, 100);
    Canvas.SetTop(hand, 100);
    canvas.Children.Add(hand);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there any particular reason that you are using `TextureBrush`?

Not really sure but maybe you should be using `ImageBrush` instead.

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
myBrush.ImageSource = 
    new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/image.jpg"));
myEllipse.Fill = myBrush;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was following a guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwka53ef%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I seem to have problem loading the image? Please see my edited OP.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of exceptions ?

Comment: See my edit, try an absolute path. Sometime VS have problems setting origin of relative URIs.